# Error: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "web3". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web3js

I have installed web3 using npm in my project. I now have a web3 folder in my node_modules folder. However, when I run my code on local server, it shows [the following error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJaYM.png):

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "web3". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../". (network.html:1

In my networks.js file, I have done "import { Web3 } from 'web3';" and in my network.html file, inside script, I have added

```
type="module" src="/js/networks.js"
```

and

```
src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@latest/dist/web3.min.js"
```

I tried to write the import statement in my .js file as a relative location i.e. ./web3 , /web3, ../web3. However, it still shows the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are directly loading the Web3 library using CDN in HTML then you don't need to install the module using NPM.
Web3 module exposes value of Web3 in global context which means, you can directly start using the Web3 in network.js file after Web3 script is loaded.

Refer: https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-fclq8f?file=js/network.js

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did "npm uninstall web3".

This is how my network.html looks like:

`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@latest/dist/web3.min.js"></script>`
  `<script type="module" src="./networks.js"></script>`

This is how my network.js looks like:

`import { Web3 } from 'web3';`

However, I am still getting the same error as below:

"Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "web3". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../". (network.html:1)".

Please help! :(

Comment: @AishwaryaGanesh, You don't need to use import statement in network.js file. Directly start using Web3 as it is exposed by library in global context.

Comment: I'm facing another issue right now. When i run my website, it says that Web3 has been deprecated and I need to use ethereum instead. But i can't find the cdn command for ethereum like the one i found for web3.min.js. Would you know where i can find the cdn.jsdeliver link for ethereum?